# Fatal Python error after Scipy Superpack installation (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scipy

Instead of using a Python distribution, I decided to install Scipy myself and stumbled upon Scipy Superpack (http://fonnesbeck.github.io/ScipySuperpack/). After installing Python 2.7.6 I followed the instructions on the website and everything seemed to work without any problems. However, once the installation was done I received a "fatal error" message as I tried to look through my modules. More specifically, the following error:

```
>>> help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

I receive the same error message in the terminal, as well as through IDLE. Despite the error message, I am able to import and use numpy, as well as other modules from the superpack.
I should mention that prior to installing the superpack I installed pip. However, this didn't induce the previously mentioned error.

I am very new to osx, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a lot of problems while trying to install all the python libraries in my mac. I searched on the web for some hours and finally got something that worked out for me. 
Scipy is here as well if you want to follow this rules instead:
https://gist.github.com/audy/4012573